# Python - removing an item from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, split

My goal for this code is to prompt a user for company, city, and state. After I print the data, I need to remove the city and then print the new data. When I run this code, it prints out the same data twice, basically not removing the city. Please help me understand when I split cityState why it's not then allowing me to remove the city.

Thanks for your help!

```
#Create a dictionary
user_data = {}

#Prompt for user data
company_name = input("Enter company name: ")
cityState = input("Enter company city and state: ")

#store the responses
user_data[company_name] = cityState

#print data
print("\nCompany details:")
for company_name, cityState in user_data.items():
    print(company_name + " " + cityState)

#split the data
temp = cityState.split()
user_data[temp[0]] = temp[1]

#remove the city
user_data.pop(temp[0])

#print the data
print("\nWith the city removed: ")
print(company_name + " " + cityState)
```

Comment: I am confused. Why do you add `temp[0]` to the dictionary and then immediately remove it without doing something with it?

Comment: My goal of temp is to split the cityState input. I figured by splitting it to temp0 and temp 1, I could then remove it.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to separate city and state from the input, you can unpack the returning list from the call to `cityState.split()` to two variables:

```
city, state = cityState.split()
print("\nWith the city removed: ")
print(company_name + " " + state)
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, as I read yours and other comments I realized my mistake of re printing the cityState data.

Answer (score 1):

In the code, `temp = cityState.split()`, the split() value is returned into temp.
The content of `cityState` doesn't change, which you happen to be printing at the end `print(company_name + " " + cityState)`.
Should do as mentioned by blhsing.

Comment: Thank you for helping me to understand this, I now see my error when I was calling to have cityState printed. Instead I just needed to switch it to temp1 to achieve the result.

Answer (score 0):

You may use 
`del user_data[<your_key>]`

Just note that you may be trying to delete a wrong key.

Answer (score 0):

to update `company_name` key from your dict with only the state you should use:

```
user_data[company_name] = temp[1]
```

in your dict, the `cityState` variable is a string that holds both the city and the state, to remove the city means to remove the city from the string not to delete some key from your dict